# How to remove times from structured data?

Tags: json, wordpress, schema, structured-data

I am trying to **remove** some of the **structured data** that The Events Calendar (TEC) plugin adds to the Events (JSON LD format). Specifically, I am trying to **remove the start and end times.** Here's how the plugin's demo site appears in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwpshindig.com%2Fevents%2F

From research, I found that TEC has a **hook** which allows the structured data to be overridden and adjusted: https://docs.theeventscalendar.com/reference/hooks/tribe_json_ld_markup/

I also found an example of how this hook could be added to my theme's functions.php file (the website is run on WordPress):

```php
add_filter( 'tribe_json_ld_markup', 'my_func' );
function my_func( $html ) {
// Do something with $html
return $html;
}
```

I don't know much PHP, so I don't know what I need to replace the comment with so that the times are removed from the structured data. I'm hoping you can help!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to find a correct action for each action, in your case you are just passing the same default html. You can modify and remove any code as follows in your sample action. Remember that you need to verify that this is the correct action for the action you want to take;

```
add_filter( 'tribe_json_ld_markup', 'my_func' );
function my_func( $html ) {
// Do something with $html

    $html = '';

return $html;
}
```

or

```
add_filter( 'tribe_json_ld_markup', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean by actions.In my case, I only want to remove the Times from the startDate and endDate schema. All other markup would remain unchanged.

Comment: Wordpress is based on actions and filters hooks, to know exactly what you can remove you need to find the right filter or action by looking at the plugin code. This code would be just an example or I posted an action that removes all the html from the filter you gave as an example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API